# Vuetify - How to change v-btn's click handler and the text conditionally?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this button:

```
<v-btn @click="handleClick">Save</v-btn>
```

The same component is used for both edit and create purpose, so I do have another boolean variable to keep track if the component is in edit/create mode. The question now is how do I change the v-btn's click handler to have different handler, and the text's changed conditionally?

At the moment I know I can do this:

```
handleClick() {
    if (editMode) {
        updateData();
    } else {
        createNew();
    }
}
// And this does not solve the problem of having the button's text fixed to "Save"
```

Or I can create two button and show them conditionally:

```
<v-btn v-if="editMode==='true'" @click="updateData">Update</v-btn>
<v-btn v-if="editMode==='false'" @click="createNewData">Save</v-btn>
```

Is there any way I can do this in with a single line of v-btn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inline handler and run the method conditionally based on `editMode` value and also for rendering the text :

```
<v-btn  @click="()=>editMode?updateData():createNewData()">{{editMode?'Update':'Save'}}</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store a handler for this button and the corresponding label.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    handler: null,
    strHandler: ""
  },
  created() {
    this.handler = this.handlerA;
    this.strHandler = "a";
  },
  methods: {
    handlerA() {
      console.log("A !")
    },
    handlerB() {
      console.log("B !")
    },
    changeHandler() {
      if (this.strHandler === "a") {
        this.handler = this.handlerB;
        this.strHandler = "b";
      }
      else {
        this.handler = this.handlerA;
        this.strHandler = "a";
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="handler">{{ strHandler }}</button>
  <button @click="changeHandler">Change</button>
</div>
```